# Is there a way to create tabs and mark selected tab based on page loaded in spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am using spartacus framework for storefront. I want to show tabs in my application and load pages based on selected tab. Is there any existing cms component or configuratio with which we can do or can i extent the cmscategorynavigation component and customize?

Comment: You can check `TabParagraphContainerComponent`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **CMSTabParagraphContainer** is used on the product details page to display tabs. A CMSTabParagraphContainer can contain SimpleCMSComponents but not for example ContentPages. You would have to extend the CMSTabParagraphContainer on the backend to also accept ContentPages, ProductPages etc. and then extend the frontend components as well. To extend Spartacus components have a look at: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/

To be honest: This seems like a lot of work if you just want a visual change to the navigation

Comment: yea. thats a lot of work.. so wanted to check if its good approach.  I ended up adding styleclass and modifying the style to look like tab.

Comment: I was able to do it by extending `CategoryNavigationComponent`.